# Dart #import from other drive: "Not allowed to load local resource"

Tags: dart, dartium

I have a library on another drive (working on m: and referencing c:). When running my dart program in Chromium I keep getting "Not allowed to load local resource..."

Is there a best practice to avoid that error while developing?

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything, libraries and project sources, in one place to avoid that error.